# Interpreting hypothesis with moderating effect in R

Tags: r, regression

I have data that is about movies: gross views, rating, votes on review site. 
My hypothesis is "rating" moderates the effect of "votes" on "views". I determined the mean votes and rating, and then built a model of gross views (gross) as:

```
model1<- lm(gross~votes_m*rating_m,mdata2)
```

The results were:

```
Call:
lm(formula = gross ~ votes_m * rating_m, data = mdata2)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-207814916  -20893642   -5018438   12947591  455882040 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      6.568e+07  9.058e+05   72.51   <2e-16 ***
votes_m          5.983e+02  1.099e+01   54.43   <2e-16 ***
rating_m         -1.987e+07  9.393e+05  -21.15   <2e-16 ***
votes_m:score_m -1.786e+02  5.844e+00  -30.56   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 48560000 on 3797 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5208,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5204 
F-statistic:  1376 on 3 and 3797 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I'm not sure if this means that "rating" moderates the effect of "votes" on "views" has significant evidence. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's confusing to me that in your text you reference the variables `rating`, `votes`, and `views`, your model `Call` has `gross`, `votes`, and `rating` (but no `views`), and your model terms have `votes`, `rating`, and `score` (no `views`, no `rating:views` interaction).

Answer (score 0):

In your case, there is a moderating effect, as the interaction term is significant, so as the direct effect of both votes and ratings variables. Important note: according to Hayes (2017), direct effects may not necessarily be needed to confirm moderation, as long as the interaction term is statistically significant. 
However, your case is stringent as all variables have very high levels of statistical significance. You would report them as *p < .001*.

**References**

Hayes, A. F. (2017). *Introduction to mediation, moderation, and conditional process analysis: A regression-based approach.* London, UK: Guilford Publications.